# Find object with value in its array

Tags: mongodb-query, lokijs

I'm using [lokijs](http://lokijs.org/), which has "mongo-similar" query language.

```
devices.insert({key:'d1', name:'Device1', users:['u1'], status: 'OK', current_wl:'123'})
    devices.insert({key:'d2', name:'Device2', users:['u1','u1'], status: 'OK', current_wl:'123'})
    devices.insert({key:'d3', name:'Device3', users:['u2','u3'], status: 'OK', current_wl:'123'})
    devices.insert({key:'d4', name:'Device4', users:['u1','u2','u3','u4'], status: 'OK', current_wl:'123'})
```

My attempt to find a device having user 'u1' in its array users returns emty list:

```
a= devices.find( {users:{ "$in" : ["u1"] }}  )
console.log("A", a);
```

Is the query correct, if the problem was for mongodb? 
Is there another way to do it in mongo?
Is there another way to do it in lokijs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about lokijs, but that's the correct query in Mongo.

If you're only ever going to query for documents that contain a single specific item in their "users" array, a simpler query for this case in Mongo would be:

```
db.collection.find({ users: "u1" })
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in lokijs :-( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (or a work-around) using `where`:

```
a= devices.where( function(obj){
      return obj.users.indexOf('u1') > -1;
   }
);
```